# New Unity Post Processing - Default Project '3d With Extras' - What effect is causing this transparency in distant objects?

Tags: unity, post-processing

I've recently seen in Unity you can start a new project with Extras included. Which is basically some post processing to make it look nicer as standard, as well as some assets/materials etc to get you started.

I have started a new project like this. And you can drive a car around a fixed camera. But if the car goes a few metres (well maybe 10-30 metres or so) into the distance there is a sort of grey fog there and it makes much of the cars mesh become more and more transparent the further you go.

It doesnt look nice at all because parts of the car (like the windscreen) can still be seen,  whilst the car body is not visible.

My question is, what is this effect called and where do I alter/disable it:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else finds the exact problem I described above. I got the answer from some very helpful guys at the Unity forums.

Its under Windows/Rendering/Lighting:
[image]